# Error php connection OpenLDAP

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

i have in VirtualBox a Ubuntu Server with OpenLdap. I upload in this server in /var/www a form in php.

But i have this error:

HTTP 500 Internal server error

and the error come when the php try to connect to OpenLdap, the code is:

```
<?php

include('ldapmanagement.php');
session_start();

$myCheck = $_POST['myCheck'];



$ldaprdn  = 'cn=admin,dc=company,dc=com';     // ldap rdn or dn
$ldappass = 'secret';  // associated password
$LDAPHOST='ldaps://localhost';
$LDAPPORT=636;
$ldaptree = "OU=people,DC=company,DC=com"; //basedn
$filter =  "uid= $_SESSION[username]";


$connection = new Connection ($LDAPHOST,$LDAPPORT,$ldaprdn,$ldappass);
$connection->connect();
$data = $connection->search($ldaptree,$filter,$myCheck);
...
 ?>
```

Comment: Look in the server's error logs for the exact error message

Comment: i have this error:  [Sat Oct 19 16:26:08 2013] [error] [client 192.168.1.57] PHP Notice:  Undefined variable: _SESSION in /var/www/formphp/controllo.php on line 15   [Sat Oct 19 16:26:13 2013] [error] [client 192.168.1.57] PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined function ldap_connect() in /var/www/formphp/ldapmanagement.php on line

Comment: `Call to undefined function ldap_connect()` that's the culprit - check out http://www.php.net/manual/en/ldap.installation.php

Comment: i try to install sudo apt-get install php5-ldap
but still not works..

Comment: now the php-ldap works but still error, [Sat Oct 19 17:07:46 2013] [error] [client 192.168.1.57] PHP Notice:  Undefined variable: _SESSION in /var/www/formphp/check.php on line 15